# Format data response of gdata

Tags: php, oauth, youtube-api

I use oauth of google to access user data, and this is my function.

```
    public function actionOauth2callback(){
    $client_key = 'client-key-here';
    $client_secret = 'client-secret-here';
    $api_key = 'api-key';
    $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/proj/user/oauth2callback';

    if (!isset($_REQUEST['code']) && !isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
            // Print the below message, if the code is not received !
        echo "Please Authorize your account: <br />";
        echo '<a href = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id='. $client_key. '&redirect_uri='.$redirect_uri .'&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me&response_type=code">Click Here to Authorize</a>';
    }
    else {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
          // Initialize a cURL session
            $ch = curl_init();

              // Set the cURL URL
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

              // The HTTP METHOD is set to POST
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

              // This option is set to TRUE so that the response
              // doesnot get printed and is stored directly in 
              // the variable
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

              // The POST variables which need to be sent along with the HTTP request
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "code=" . $_REQUEST['code'] . "&client_id=" . $client_key . "&client_secret=" . $client_secret . "&redirect_uri=".$redirect_uri."&grant_type=authorization_code");

              // Execute the cURL request       
              $data = curl_exec($ch);

              // Close the cURL connection
              curl_close($ch);
              // Decode the JSON request and remove the access token from it
              $data = json_decode($data);

              $access_token = $data->access_token;

              // Set the session access token
              $_SESSION['access_token'] = $data->access_token;
        }
        else {
          // If session access token is set
            $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
        }
        // Initialize another cURL session
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set all the options and execute the session
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?v=2&access_token=" . $access_token);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        // Get the data from the JSON response
        print_r($data);         
        $data = json_decode($data);
        print_r($data);
    }
```

But I have problem with format of data response, it's not JSON or XML, just `string` like this

```
tag:youtube.com,2008:user:JNbz_VZ2LG1WD4zjKEY9uQ2010-06-02T13:11:26.000Z2012-09-29T20:32:13.000ZHuyTranHoanghttps://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/chenhuanghuiJNbz_VZ2LG1WD4zjKEY9uQ22HuymTran HoangVNJNbz_VZ2LG1WD4zjKEY9uQchenhuanghui
```

Anybody can tell me, what wrong am I? 
Thank you so much

Comment: can you see view source of your page ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an XML file and you are not looking the the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Google Data APIs support `JSON` output through the use of the `alt` parameter  You need to Look at  [Developer's Guide: JSON / JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json)

Your URL should look like this

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json
```

Comment: :thank you about your answer, and I have another problem with json format of data response, have some key is `$t`, when I use json_decode, but don't know how to get data from key `$t`. Ex: I get user info, data response have `"name": {"$t": "Huy Tran Hoang"}`, I use `name->$t` to get value of key $t but I get error with message is : `Undefined variable: t`. Show how can I get value of key $t